# How to insert bulk data one db to another db?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I want to copy some old data from one database to another new database.
I wrote a script that works, but I want to same change in my old data.

Present my data format is:

```
user {
_id: 1,
username: "jon",
email: "jon@gmail.com"
}
```

But I want this format:

```
  user {
   _id: "621721aed6d2481c999429e5",
    username: "jon",
    email: "jon@gmail.com",
    old_id: 1
    }
```

My script is:

```
var bulk = db.getSiblingDB("blog-new")["users"].initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.getCollection("users").find().forEach(function (d) {
     bulk.insert(d);
});
bulk.execute();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
solve this issue using this script-

```
var bulk = db.getSiblingDB("user-new")["users"].initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.getCollection("users").find().forEach(function (d) {
    d.old_id = NumberInt(d._id)
    d._id = ObjectId()
    print("user", d);
    bulk.insert(d);
});

bulk.execute();
```